# saltstack pattern match failing

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to replace a line in httpd.conf in packer using masterless salt. I always check the pattern using grep command and if it works then the same will work in saltstack too but this time it fails. As I am not good in regular expression please help on this.

I want to replace the below line

```
CustomLog "|'/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/bin/rotatelogs' '/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log' 10M" common
```

with

```
CustomLog /apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log common
```

So I used

```
Log-file-update:
  file.replace:
    - name: /apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - pattern: 'CustomLog \"\|'/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/bin/rotatelogs' '/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log' 10M\" common'
    - repl: 'CustomLog /apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log common'
    - append_if_not_found: False
```

But its failing. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

The below is the error.

```
<pre> <code>
amazon-ebs: [CRITICAL] Rendering SLS 'base:install' failed: while parsing a block mapping
    amazon-ebs:   in "<unicode string>", line 46, column 7:
    amazon-ebs:         - pattern: 'CustomLog \"\|'/apps/C ...
    amazon-ebs:           ^
    amazon-ebs: expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
    amazon-ebs:   in "<unicode string>", line 46, column 32:
    amazon-ebs:         - pattern: 'CustomLog \"\|'/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportals ...
    amazon-ebs:                                    ^
```

Comment: Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the first `'` in your pattern.

This should work,

```
Log-file-update:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/pki/tls/certs/test
    - pattern: CustomLog \"|\'/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/bin/rotatelogs\' \'/apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log\' 10M\" common
    - repl: CustomLog /apps/CA/secure-proxy/bizportalsps/httpd/logs/access_log common
    - append_if_not_found: False
```